# Multiple custom post types under one admin menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I'm not sure where to start with this one.

I want to have 4 custom post types (Gigs, Venues, Holidays and Potentials) listed under a main heading of Events Manager, but don't want Events Manager to be a custom post type.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help you - please clarify what "Events Manager" is, what code you are currently using to output the menu, whether this is indeed a nav menu (a particular feature in WordPress) or a menu generated by other means.

Comment: Events Manager just needs to be a top-level menu name, it doesn't need to do anything, other than contain the custom post types within it. So far, I have tried creating a custom post type and appending the other custom post types using 'show-in-menu- => 'edit.php?post_type=events-manager', but as I have said, I don't want Events Manager to be a custom post type.

Comment: Got it! You should edit your question to make it clear you are referring to the **admin** menu. I will work on a solution and get back to you.

Comment: I will ensure to edit the question in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create a "placeholder" menu that you can then assign all your post types to:

```
function wpse_226690_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Events Manager',
        'Events Manager',
        'read',
        'events-manager',
        '', // Callback, leave empty
        'dashicons-calendar',
        1 // Position
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_226690_admin_menu' );
```

And then in your `register_post_type` calls:

```
'show_in_menu' => 'events-manager',
```

Tada!

Comment: I had tried something close to this earlier, but was using a different way to 'show_in_menu'. I've also watered down the amount of data to create the custom post type and along with your code I now have it working as expected, so thank you very much!